# My emacs client automagically terminates when switching applications [OSX iTerm2]

Tags: macos, emacs, iterm2, emacsclient

I try to be brave and switch from `vi` to `emacs`. 
Now, I set up Emacs 26 on macOS via homebrew and start Emacs as daemon in the background.

I can use files using `emacsclient -t`. However, whenever I bring the Terminal into the background emacsclient exits within a few seconds.

See example Video here: https://cloud.familie-ganter.de/s/QwbK8cFBHnPjQ4d

I did a plain install. My init file does not contain anything except what you see in the video. The funny thing is whenever I start `emacs` directly in the Terminal, nothing at all happens when bringing it to the background.

What seems to be the problem? 
I am lost …

I expect it to be something dumb and simple  --  so please be nice, this is my first stackoverflow post.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs in Ask Different.

Comment: Wow – now please explain this to me. This question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1264903/emacs-23-emacsclient-arguments?rq=1 was accepted and answered here ...

Comment: I don't agree?  Also why I don't have the permission to close questions on my own.  But you don't think a site that is *Q&A for power users of Apple hardware and software* would be more appropriate?

Comment: **Ha!** I can answer my own question. Updating to `emacs 26.3`did solve the Issue, it does no longer appear. Strange though.  ---   now, how do I close this question ?

Comment: if you think your answer is useful, you could post it and accept it.  Alternatively, just delete it